# Convert Type1 To type2 Using LINQ with Subselect projection

Tags: .net, asp.net, linq

In the following code I want the project Id and name of TList and cast them to List. How do I do that?

```
List<ListItem> nameItems = new List<ListItem>();
TList<ProductCode> items = GetAllProductCode();
//WANT TO SUBSELECT ID, NAME OF ITEMS IN nameItems 
nameItems = (from item in items select new (item.Id, item.Name)).Cast<ListItem>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Well even after you've changed that to `new { item.Id, item.Name }` the cast will fail, because you're not actually *selecting* `ListItem` values.

You need to write a projection which creates instances of `ListItem`. It's not clear whether this is a built-in `ListItem` class or your own one, but something like this may well be what you want:

```
List<ListItem> nameItems = items.Select(item => new ListItem(item.Id, item.Name))
                                .ToList();
```

If you could tell us more about what `ListItem` is, that would help a lot.

(It's also not clear why you're mentioning subselect projections in the title - I can't see anything relevant to subselects within the question.)